# Trigger Chrome extension from javascript function in webpage

Tags: javascript, events, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to trigger an event in my chrome extension from inside my websites javascript (not the content/background scripts of the extension)

For example

**extension**

```
    function focusWindow () {
        chrome.tabs.query({ currentWindow: false, active: true }, function (tabs) {
            chrome.windows.update(tabs[0].windowId, {focused: true, state: "maximized" })
        });
    }

on.event("CountDownOver"){
    focusWindow();
}
```

**Website JS**

```
if(backgroundCountDownValue == 0){
    triggerCustomeEvent("CountDownOver");
}
```

I've had to pseudo-code this, because i can't post the way I actually want to use this, but i hope this makes sense

Comment: 1) [external messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage), 2) standard DOM messaging via CustomEvent or window.postMessage.

Comment: @wOxxOm
Would you be able to provide an example of any of these doing what i want?
I've looked at each and can't seem to get results

Comment: I think you can find many examples by googling for the API function names I gave.